# SharePoint bugs with ecbmenu after migration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

[Problem with ecbmenu highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60oao.png)

[How the ecbmenu should show instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUOoU.png)

Hi, I'm new to sharepoint and alone in my company handling sharepoint issues. Recently after migration, I ran into this issue. Does anyone know what is this related to? And how I should go about to attempt fixing this? Thanks!

Just to add on some codes related to this. I doubt the issue is in here however. Probably related to some javascript code.

[Html code of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R7Q1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Whether this issue occurs only in migrated site collection or also occurs in newly created site collection?

Please clear browser cache then have a test.

Comment: Hi, issue occurs only in the new site. The image that I have linked, one is from intranet sharepoint and the one with the issue is from sharepoint online. Problem is occurring for everyone in the company.